# vb to c# conversion for preprocessors

Tags: c#

Can anyone help in this conversion, i have modified it after using some conversion tool but it is not working.

```
    Public Sub New()

#If CONFIG = "Debug" Or CONFIG = "Release" Then
        strDBCNDN = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("").ToString()
        strDBCMDR = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("").ToString()
        strDBCQueueReader = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("").ToString()
#ElseIf CONFIG = "QA" Then
        strDBCNDN = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("").ToString()
        strDBCMDR = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("").ToString()
        strDBCQueueReader = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("").ToString()
#ElseIf CONFIG = "QA2" Then
        strDBCNDN = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("").ToString()
        strDBCMDR = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("").ToString()
        strDBCQueueReader = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("").ToString()
#ElseIf CONFIG = "Prod" Then
        strDBCNDN = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("").ToString()
        strDBCMDR = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("").ToString()
        strDBCQueueReader = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("").ToString()
#End If
        isConnectionIssue = False

        Try
/*Here some code to fetch data from data base */
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Converted in C# as below also used has define to define used variable on top of the page

```
public SameMethod()
    {


          #if CONFIG== Debug || CONFIG ==Release
                         {
                            strDBCNDN = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();
                            strDBCMDR = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();
                            strDBCQueueReader = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();
                         }
            #elif CONFIG==QA
                        {
                            strDBCNDN = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();
                            strDBCMDR = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();
                            strDBCQueueReader = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();
                        }

            #elif CONFIG== QA2
                        {
                            strDBCNDN = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();
                            strDBCMDR = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();
                            strDBCQueueReader = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();
                        }

            #elif CONFIG==Prod
                        {
                            strDBCNDN = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();
                            strDBCMDR = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();
                            strDBCQueueReader = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();
                        }
       #endif
        isConnectionIssue = false;

        try
        {
            strAppName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""].ToString();

           /*some code for database*/
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? What's the error? That will help us out a lot!

Comment: There is no build or compile error, when i put break point over there it does not read anything at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx - you won't be able to do comparisons such as `CONFIG == Debug`. That's because the C# `#IF` preprocessor can only check if a symbol is defined. These symbols can only be true or false.

You may consider replacing these with `#IF DEBUG` and `#ELIF QA`, because that way you can define the `DEBUG` and `QA` symbols for each build configuration.